# kernel error in CentOS 6.9

Tags: centos, kernel, vmware, reboot

Recently I see these messeges in my `/var/log/messeges` and `dmesg | less`:

```
 kernel: INFO: task flush-8:32:1065 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
 kernel:      Not tainted 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1
 kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this 
 message.
 kernel: flush-8:32    D 0000000000000004     0  1065      2 0x00000000
 kernel: ffff88063389b840 0000000000000046 0000000000000000 0005120000000001
 kernel: ffff880636304ce0 ffff8806363098c0 00022e760ddb7d3a ffff88062db31360
 kernel: 0000000000011200 000000012494c97a ffff88062e0fbad8 ffff88063389bfd8
 kernel: Call Trace:
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d11e0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
 kernel: [<ffffffff8154ae83>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d1220>] sync_buffer+0x40/0x50
 kernel: [<ffffffff8154b73a>] __wait_on_bit_lock+0x5a/0xc0
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d11e0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
 kernel: [<ffffffff8154b818>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit_lock+0x78/0x90
 kernel: [<ffffffff810a68c0>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d1540>] ? end_buffer_async_write+0x0/0x190
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d13c6>] __lock_buffer+0x36/0x40
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d26c5>] __block_write_full_page+0x305/0x330
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d1540>] ? end_buffer_async_write+0x0/0x190
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d27d0>] block_write_full_page_endio+0xe0/0x120
 kernel: [<ffffffffa0211d00>] ? buffer_unmapped+0x0/0x20 [ext3]
 kernel: [<ffffffff811d2825>] block_write_full_page+0x15/0x20
 kernel: [<ffffffffa021288d>] ext3_ordered_writepage+0x1ed/0x240 [ext3]
 kernel: [<ffffffff81142367>] __writepage+0x17/0x40
 kernel: [<ffffffff8114362d>] write_cache_pages+0x1fd/0x4c0
 kernel: [<ffffffff81009913>] ? __switch_to+0x2f3/0x340
 kernel: [<ffffffff81142350>] ? __writepage+0x0/0x40
 kernel: [<ffffffff81299899>] ? cpumask_next_and+0x29/0x50
 kernel: [<ffffffff81064054>] ? find_busiest_group+0x254/0xa50
 kernel: [<ffffffff81143914>] generic_writepages+0x24/0x30
 kernel: [<ffffffff81143955>] do_writepages+0x35/0x40
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c6f1d>] writeback_single_inode+0xdd/0x290
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c731d>] writeback_sb_inodes+0xbd/0x170
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c747b>] writeback_inodes_wb+0xab/0x1b0
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c7873>] wb_writeback+0x2f3/0x410
 kernel: [<ffffffff8154a68e>] ? schedule+0x3ee/0xb70
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c7b3d>] wb_do_writeback+0x1ad/0x250
 kernel: [<ffffffff8108f000>] ? process_timeout+0x0/0x10
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c7c86>] bdi_writeback_thread+0xa6/0x220
 kernel: [<ffffffff811c7be0>] ? bdi_writeback_thread+0x0/0x220
 kernel: [<ffffffff810a63ae>] kthread+0x9e/0xc0
 kernel: [<ffffffff8100c28a>] child_rip+0xa/0x20
 kernel: [<ffffffff810a6310>] ? kthread+0x0/0xc0
 kernel: [<ffffffff8100c280>] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20
```

Today one of VM machines rebooted. When I checked `messeges`, I saw above messeges and then some database errors. That network had a problem and this machine lost connection with its primary and just rebooted. My question is: what are these kernel messeges and where should I search for problem? Do they have something to do with network? Does it only happens on VM machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning is due to resource starvation.

If in a VM, it might be a clue the host is oversubscribed.

Mind you it is a warning (hence the INFO keyword), it can be ignored. However I advise dealing with the underlying issues that are causing it, also because they are bound to worsen over time.

I would go for lack or resources/overuse of I/O storage.

You can also try to run:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=10
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
```

If that works out for you, put it permanently, for applying it at boot time, in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5
vm.dirty_ratio = 10
```

See [Linux Kernel panic issue: How to fix hung_task_timeout_secs and blocked for more than 120 seconds problem](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/)

> By default Linux uses up to 40% of the available memory for file
>   system caching. After this mark has been reached the file system
>   flushes all outstanding data to disk causing all following IOs going
>   synchronous. For flushing out this data to disk this there is a time
>   limit of 120 seconds by default. In the case here the IO subsystem is
>   not fast enough to flush the data withing 120 seconds. As IO subsystem
>   responds slowly and more requests are served, System Memory gets
>   filled up resulting in the above error, thus serving HTTP requests.